# Impossible to change sreen resolution on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, intel-graphics

I have recently installed windows 7 on my old pc which until lq was running windows xp sp3 everything went well except that the resolution of the screen remains blocked on 640x480 which is the rewolution by default when windows does not detect the graphics card. this meanwhile I would still like to keep my windows 7 running but with better graphics. my question is how to get around this? is there a hack to improve the graphics?

my pc is:

- RAM: 760MB
- DD: 40GB
- chipset: brookdale-G graphic chip accelerate vga bios

  - Gateware E-2000

Comment: Just a thought, but you may want to simply buy a graphics card. Based on personal experience with a similar upgrade, it's seems likely you can probably find a suitable one for under $50. That said, you should probably double check the exact hardware you have before purchasing anything.

Comment: Make and specific model of PC will help us help you, thanks.

Comment: @Moab I updated my question

Comment: You need to install drivers for your GPU. You need CPU and GPU Model No. to search for them.
However, as your computer is so old there might not be drivers avalible that work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using a wrong driver package. Start by checking your motherboard model. Press Windows+R keys simultaneously and type "msinfo32" without quotes, on Run dialog, press Enter. A lot of information will be presented to you. Look for manufacture (OEM) and system model. Then go ahead and reach manufacture's website, search by model, using the information you just gathered and download the stock VGA driver ( and chipset too ! ) . Install them and that would solve it